# How to skip the login page of Salesforce?

Tags: java, selenium, salesforce, rest-assured, salesforce-lightning

I am currently automating test of Salesforce application and in the automation suite, logging into the application is performed numerous time. I am using Selenium + Java for the purpose of automation.

Is there any way to skip the multiple logins via; like if we can hit some login endpoint and inject the response cookies to the browser instance. Or if we can log in once and somehow save the session id or necessary cookies which could then be injected to new browser instances so that we can skip login step.

Also, I want to add on that I am using Salesforce lightning.

Any sort of help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi! Did you solve your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> WebDriver has the functionality to read the cookies from the browser before closing it and then restore the cookies in the new browser window.

```
@Test
public void login_state_should_be_restored() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.example.com/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("12345");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

    Assert.assertTrue(
            driver.findElement(By.id("welcome")).isDisplayed());

    //Before closing the browser, read the cookies
    Set allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

    driver.close();

    //open a new browser window
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //restore all cookies from the previous session
    for(Cookie cookie : allCookies) {
        driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
    }

    driver.get("http://www.example.com/login");
    Assert.assertTrue(
            driver.findElement(By.id("welcome")).isDisplayed());

    driver.close();
}
```

For more in details, please check the [link](https://www.testingexcellence.com/webdriver-how-to-restore-cookies-in-new-browser-window/)

Hope this will help you.